# how to use <input type="" class="" form-control" id="" placeholder="">?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Normally we use:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
           <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.UserName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
            </td>
            </table>
```

But I'm using bootsrap and I want to take de information of the txtboxes.
My code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @html(a => a.name) input type="text" class="form-control" id="usertxt" placeholder="Your name">
</div>

 @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.password)
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

I'm not sure how to do it. Help? :D

Comment: You should google this to find examples. This is not an error in the code so we have a look at it. You are trying to learn basics of something which can be found easily on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add additional attributes to form controls generated by HTML Helpers, then you can use the `htmlAttribues` parameter of one of `TextBoxFor`'s overloads.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "usertxt", placeholder = "Your name" })
</div>
```

The second parameter here is an `object` containing all the additional attributes you want to add to the `input`. And `TextBoxFor` generates an input of `type="text"`, so you don't have to add it explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear still. Please be specific about what you are trying to do. 
Anyway, there are two ways to write server-side code & html code together. 
1. Keep HTML as it is and write server-side code within required html tag. 
2. Wrap html code with server-side code.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to show the value into the text field, you should use the value="" attribute in the field. And then it will be displayed into the text field box.

Example

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="usr">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" value="User Name">
</div>
```